# $y=(25-x^2)^{1/2},\;y=3$ find the volume

Tags: calculus, volume

Here is the question if $y=(25-x^2)^{1/2},$ $y=3$ find the volume?(about x-axis)

I draw this and I have circle and line
But the problem is when y=3 we will have two area and both of them are enclosed by the given curve
Wich of them should I choose ? Thanks all

Comment: You must select the above part because the below part is not closed by both of them

Comment: As you see in the following plot interval is $[-4,4]$ which is between the intersection of them.

Comment: Are you just looking for the region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Be careful that the below part is not closed by them, and only above part of the line is closed by them.
$$
V=\pi\int_{-4}^4\left(\left(\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)^2-3^2 \right)\,dx
$$

Comment: Because of symmetry as you can see in the plot you can take it, then multiply the answer by 2.

Comment: Oh thank you, should I write the integral from -4 to 4 of $25-x^2 -3^2$

Comment: Your right, I have edited my answer and written it.

Comment: @FarshadNahangi: Farshad, kash sheklo kami rangi mikardi ta wazeh tar beshe. Karet alliye. :+)

Comment: @B.S. Merci, kare shoma ham kheili khoob bood, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

The desire integral is indeed as follows: $$\pi\int_{-4}^{+4}(y_1^2-y_2^2)dx$$ wherein $y_1$ is the upper curve along side the interval $I [-4,4]$ and $y_2$ is the downer one. All we are doing here is based on this [method](http://www2.bc.cc.ca.us/resperic/Math6A/Lectures/ch6/2/shell.htm). The following plot shows the volume of revolution:

[image]

Comment: Awesome animation! How'd you create it? +1

Comment: @amWhy: You know that. Without Maple I 'll be lost. :)

Comment: I suspected it was via Maple! Very nice to have: and it's the one I *don't* have :-(

Comment: @amWhy: By using `VolumeOfRevolution` code, it will be visualize easily. Take a look at its Help menu.